# SQLData reading mapped objects with an interface

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, types

**Introduction**

I am creating an interface read from mapped objects on a OracleSQL database. So far so good, I successfully created the TYPEs and TABLEs but when reading them with the `java.sql.SQLData` it's giving me this casting error.

**Code**

```
public class EmpresaSqlData extends Empresa implements SQLData {

    private String sql_type = "USER.EMPRESA";

    public EmpresaSqlData() {}

    public EmpresaSqlData(String cif, String nom, Contacte contacte) {
        super(cif, nom, contacte);
    }    

    public EmpresaSqlData(String cif, String nom) {
        super(cif, nom);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        sql_type = typeName;
        setNom(stream.readString());
        setCif(stream.readNString());//Write the object
        setContacte(stream.readObject(new Contacte)); //Fix??
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(getNom());
        stream.writeString(getCif());
        stream.writeObject(new ContacteSqlData());        
    }    
}
```

The above is need afterwards when I execute queries such as:

```
@Override
    public List<EmpresaSqlData> findAll() {
        EmpresaSqlData empresaSqlDataSQLData;
        List<EmpresaSqlData> corpList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT VALUE (e) FROM empreses e";

       try (Connection conn = cf.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement 
                    = conn.prepareStatement(query);){

            //Initial connection setup
            conn.setTypeMap(map);

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next()){      
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1, EmpresaSqlData.class)); //Error here "Type of column not valid"
            }            

            return corpList;              

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmpresaDAOImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Research**

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/oraoot3.htm) at "*Implementing readSQL() and writeSQL() Methods*" (Ctrl+C and Ctrl+F + Enter to get to the point) it states that:

```
· The readSQL() method takes as input a SQLInput stream and a string that indicates the SQL type name of the data (in other words, the name of the Oracle object type, such as EMPLOYEE)
```

**Problem**

Then I have tried to read the SQLobject returned by `readSQL()` and cast it to the Java object `Contacte`

```
setContacte((Contacte)stream.readObject());
```

which gives me this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.STRUCT cannot be cast to activitat3.logica.Contacte
    at activitat3.logica.EmpresaSqlData.readSQL(EmpresaSqlData.java:44)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.toClass(STRUCT.java:662)
    at oracle.sql.STRUCT.toJdbc(STRUCT.java:599)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:110)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getObject(GeneratedStatement.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getObject(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:761)
    at activitat3.dades.impl.EmpresaDAOImpl.findAll(EmpresaDAOImpl.java:184)
    at activitat3.test.Main.llistarEmpreses(Main.java:330)
    at activitat3.test.Main.main(Main.java:93)
```

This Exception states that an object read with the `readSQL()` method from `java.sql.SQLData` can not be casted to a Java object.

**How I am supposed to work with an Object this way?**

readInt() returns Integer, readString returns String, but readObject() can not be casted or given a custom Object?

**Goal**

I want to read a mapped object from an OracleSQL database [this way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html).

Comment: Your `EmpresaSqlData` class implements `SQLData`, but does your `Contacte` class do the same?  You haven't specified the definition of the type `USER.EMPRESA`, but it looks as if one of its fields is another custom Oracle type which corresponds to a `Contacte` in the same way that `USER.EMPRESA` corresponds to `EmpresaSqlData`.

Comment: I actually found out why thank to your comment, I checked the Map object and I had commented the USER.CONTACTE. To there it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems the problem was that a similar mapping for the `Contacte` class was missing or incomplete.

The stacktrace shows that the `EmpresaSqlData` class is being entered, so the mapping for this type is working.  If the `Contacte` class is not being mapped from the database, then there is presumably no such mapping of an Oracle type either directly to this class, or, as suggested by your `EmpresaSqlData`, to a subclass of it.

Comment: Yep, forgot to add into the map the object. So if you answer that. I will totally accept it.